# What was the exact purpose of Dooku with giving this information?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In Star Wars: Attacks of the Clones, why did Dooku tell Obi-wan about the Senate being under the control of a Sith Lord? Was it because Dooku had a back-stab plan for Sidious or just because Sidious had wanted him to do it?

[image]

Comment: It's all part of the Sith being arrogant and gloating over what they perceive to be their inevitable victory. A villain confident of victory likes playing with his victim, intentionally giving him either a false sense of hope for the kicks or a legit chance for sport and challenge. Dooku rightly guessed that it is safe to reveal this because, let's face it, the late Jedi Order are more corrupt and arrogant than the Sith and too blinded by the dark side to find out the truth even with that hint. Obi-Wan foolishly didn't believe him because he thinks it's impossible for the Jedi not to sense it.

Comment: Also, the Rule of Two requires the Sith Apprentice to eventually attempt to overthrow his master. Perhaps Dooku / Darth Tyrannus was using this as a step in that plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dooku is actually playing a pretty clever game here. It would definitely serve the Sith's plans of Galactic domination if they can get a member of the Jedi Council to join them and he knows that the Jedi, and *Obi-Wan in particular*, have been harbouring serious doubts about the motives of Palpatine and the Senate.

By offering a captive Obi-Wan some important-sounding (but ultimately worthless) information about Sidious' secret name and and a half-truth that the Senate is under the influence of the Sith, he hopes to convince Obi-Wan that despite their violent ways, the Separatists are actually on the side of the angels in this conflict, valiantly fighting against a Sith-inspired Senate plot to destroy their freedom. Unfortunately (for Dooku), Obi-Wan overheard his battle plans a few minutes before and is not fooled by Dooku's lies.